# How to convert a time value from 22:30 to 1030p

Tags: excel

I have multiple excel entries in 24 hour time format, that I need to convert to another very specific format.

e.g:

22:00 = 10p

6:00  = 6a

14:30 = 230p

You get the gist; I'm not sure as the length of the resulting time string is not always constant. I.e if the time ends in "00" it only has 2 or 3 characters. if it ends in anything else, it should have 4 or 5 strings

Comment: Are the input entries in string format or are they date-epoch numbers formatted as time?

Answer (score 1):

This converts to a new string value in a different cell.

Value to convert in cell A1

```
=TEXT(A1,IF(MINUTE(A1)=0,"ha/p","hmma/p"))
```

Examples:

```
22:00   10p
06:00   6a
6:00    6a
14:30   230p
```

Seems to work whether values are actual Excel times (eg 14:30:00) or strings eg '14:30.

Comment: Pretty sure you want your "minute" choice as `"hmma/p"  else `2:01` => `21a`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You are probably right ... Have edited.

Comment: beauty. This saved me a lot of trouble. cheers